# What is the difference between these two ways of using buttons and an OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a pretty crappy book so I am not sure for their reasoning for using either form.

The first way that it would go about it would be like this

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnButton)

 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//code code code }
```

Then our book wants to use Global Variables instead of local, so it randomly starts using a different way to go about things

```
Button btButton;
//Done as Global Variable.

btButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnButton);
btButton.setOnClickListener(bButton);


Button.OnClickListener bButton = new Button.OnClickListener(){
//code }
```

It is things like this that my book is horrible at and one reason why I will not be buying the next installment of it. I hate when it just changes the way it does things without any real reason. So can anyone really tell me the difference here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone says, there is no difference-- but nobody has explained why.

`Button` extends `View`.

When you are using `onClickListener`, you are using the one defined in `View`.  Almost always, this one will work-- it won't with `Dialogs`, and maybe some other classes.

If you explicitly say `Button.onClickListener`, you are referencing the `onClickListener` defined in the `Button` class, and since `Button` extends `View`, this is the same as using the generic `onClickListener.`

There is also the inner anonymous vs explicit, but this is more of a preference.  You will get better performance using a static onClickListener than in inner anonymous, simply because there is less garbage collection necessary, but you won't notice it unless you have 30 or so anonymous inner listeners.

Comment: Wow thanks. Yeah, I have realized that I really need to get more familiar with Java than I am and this is probably one of those issues that would be clear as water if I had a better understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Both are same..
First one uses anonymous inner class, and secon on creates an object of listner and pass it to method..

Second method comes with advantag of reusabbility of same listner instance.. but first on is preferred as generally we have different listners for every buttons

Answer (score 2):

You have nothing to worry about. They both do the same thing. In the first example you are creating the instance of OnClickListener when you set it to the button.

In the second case, the onClickListener has already been created beforehand, and you are passing in a reference to it.

Different people prefer to do it different ways, and they lend themselves to different functionality.

Obviously by setting it equal to bButton in the second example allows you to manipulate it later or use it in other button listeners, whereas you don't have a copy of the first one to do that with.

So if you wanted to use the exact same code for several buttons, the second option would allow you to add the listener to all the buttons.

Hope that seems a little clearer now

Comment: Ahh ok. See, I am half decent at this stuff when it is explained, but it drives me UP THE WALL when it is just like, HEY I am going to start doing it this way and give no reasoning why this way may be used.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference between the two examples you posted. Your book probably did not cover this because this is more of a Java question then Android. The first one your just dynamically declaring your OnClickListener instance, where on the second you declared it stataically and then referenced it. In execution they will behave exactly the same.

You can use the second example if for example you have more then one button. You can pass your OnClickListener to each and then process which button is pressed from within the OnClickListener instead of having a separate OnClickListener for each button.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, when you write :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });
```

It will be converted to the following code at compile time :

```
Button.OnClickListener anonymous_listener = new Button.OnClickListener() { ... };
button.setOnClickListener(anonymous_listener);
```

The second example you provided is bad. It stores a useless reference to a `OnClickListener` which will never be used somewhere else than in your `onCreate()` method. It's only 8 bytes lost or so, but still it's useless and should be defined as a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

Assume it have created a listener object on the fly and passed it to your **setOnClickListener**. This style is known in java as Anonymous Inner Classes. and second one is straightforward.

```
Button.OnClickListener bButton = new Button.OnClickListener(){
```

The reason why used **Button.OnClickListener** is that **OnClickListener** is in **View Class**. and **Button Class inherits it from View**. So to avoid import statement , we used directly **Button.OnClickListener**.